# Showing and hiding fragments are not committed (don't occur) immediately when SwipeRefreshLayout is refreshing

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, instagram, fragmentmanager

So basically what I'm working on is very similar to Instagram application, where there're a number of tabs and users can switch to any tab without any delay no matter what there's anything going on, such as refreshing, reloading, and etc. It also uses back button to go back to the previous preserved tab.

In order to achieve this, I've used `FragmentManager` with `FragmentTransaction` to show and hide each fragment which represents each tab. I didn't use `replace` or `attach` / `detach` because they destroy view hierarchy of previous tab.

My implementation works pretty well except that showing and hiding fragments are not committed (I highly doubt that this is a right word to say but so far that's how I understood the flow.), or don't occur immediately **when `SwipeRefreshLayout` is refreshing on the fragment (to be hidden) which was added to `FragmentManager` later than the one to show**.

My implementation follows the rules like these. Let's say we have 4 tabs and my *MainActivity* is showing the first tab, say *FirstFragment*, and the user selects the second tab, *SecondFragment*. Because *SecondFragment* had never been added before, I add it to `FragmentManager` by using `FragmentTransaction.add` and hide *FirstFragment* by using `FragmentTransaction.hide`. If the user selects the first tab again, because *FirstFragment* was previously added to `FragmentManager`, it doesn't add but only show *FirstFragment* and just hide *SecondFragment*. And selecting between these two tabs works smoothly.

But when the user "refreshes" *SecondFragment*'s `SwipeRefreshLayout` and selects the first tab, `FragmentTransaction` waits for *SecondFragment*'s refresh to be finished and commits(?) the actual transaction. The strange thing is that the transaction is committed immediately the other way around, from *FirstFragment*'s refresh to *SecondFragment*.

Because this occurs by the order of addition to `FragmentManager`, I doubt that the order of addition somehow affects backstack of fragments and there might exists something like UI thread priority so that it forces the fragment transaction to be taken place after later-added fragment's UI transition finishes. But I just don't have enough clues to solve the issue. I've tried attach / detach and backstack thing on `FragmentTransaction` but couldn't solve the issue. I've tried both `FragmentTransaction.commit` and `FragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss` but neither solved the issue.

These are my *MainActivity*'s sample code.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> mFragmentsStack; // This is simple psuedo-stack which only stores
                                            // the order of fragments stack to collaborate
                                            // when back button is pressed.
private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    mFragmentsStack = new ArrayList<>();
    mFragmentsList = new ArrayList<>();
    mFragmentsList.add(FirstFragment.newInstance());
    mFragmentsList.add(SecondFragment.newInstance());
    mFragmentsList.add(ThirdFragment.newInstance());
    mFragmentsList.add(FourthFragment.newInstance());
    mMainTab = (MainTab) findViewById(R.id.main_tab);
    mMainTab.setOnMainTabClickListener(this);

    int currentTab = DEFAULT_TAB;

    mFragmentsStack.add(currentTab);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_frame_layout,
            mFragmentsList.get(currentTab), String.valueOf(currentTab)).commit();
    mMainTab.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
}

// This is custom interface.
@Override
public void onTabClick(int oldPosition, int newPosition) {
    if (oldPosition != newPosition) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // First hide the old tab.
        fragmentTransaction.hide(mFragmentsList.get(oldPosition));

        // Recalculate the fragment stack.
        if (mFragmentsStack.contains(newPosition)) {
            mFragmentsStack.remove((Integer) newPosition);
        }
        mFragmentsStack.add(newPosition);

        // Add new fragment if it's not added before, or show new fragment which was already hidden.
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(newPosition));
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_layout, mFragmentsList.get(newPosition),
                    String.valueOf(newPosition));
        }

        // Commit the transaction.
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}

// It mimics the tab behavior of Instagram Android application.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // If there's only one fragment on stack, super.onBackPressed.
    // If it's not, then hide the current fragment and show the previous fragment.
    int lastIndexOfFragmentsStack = mFragmentsStack.size() - 1;
    if (lastIndexOfFragmentsStack - 1 >= 0) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.hide(mFragmentsList.get(mFragmentsStack.get(lastIndexOfFragmentsStack)));
        fragmentTransaction.show(mFragmentsList.get(mFragmentsStack.get(lastIndexOfFragmentsStack - 1)));
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        mMainTab.setCurrentTab(mFragmentsStack.get(lastIndexOfFragmentsStack - 1));
        mFragmentsStack.remove(lastIndexOfFragmentsStack);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling executePendingTransactions()? Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: @dora I added `executePendingTransactions()` after commit statements but it doesn't work. I'm wondering if it's a right place because what the document says seems to be the answer for my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just faced the same issue with only difference - I'm switching fragments on toolbar buttons click.
I've managed to get rid of overlapping fragments overriding onHiddenChanged:

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    if (hidden) {
        yourSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've thought about this, `setRefreshing` to false when changing tabs, but I didn't like the idea of forcing UI state to be different from what's actually going on. However I can't find any workaround so this would do the closest job. Thank you.

Comment: Save my day!! I use infinite view pager with SwipeRefreshLayout. The refresh indicator will not show again if I keep scroll right to the same view second time => ex 0,1,2,0,1,2  . setRefreshing(false) in destroyItem() and it works!!!